# How can I get the value of an attribute for a method that has duplicates?

Tags: c#, linq, attributes, coded-ui-tests

I have some code that generates a report based off the attributes of my CodedUI test project.  I want to be able to add the TestCategoryAttribute to this report but I don't know how to adapt my code to allow for duplicate attributes like below:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Smoke")]
[TestCategory("Feature1")]
public void CodedUITest()
{
}
```

The code below works when I only have one TestCategory but will not work with multiple test categories as above:

```
//Other code above to find all CodedUI classes and all public, nonstatic methods with the TestMethod attribute

//find method with testcategory attribute
if (attrs.Any(x => x is TestCategoryAttribute))
{
   var testcategoryAttr = (TestCategoryAttribute)attrs.SingleOrDefault(x => x is TestCategoryAttribute);
   string testCategories = string.Join(", ", testcategoryAttr.TestCategories.Select(v => v.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: You can't really ask for `SingleOrDefault` and get multiple items... Not sure what exactly you need, but definitely not `SingleOrDEfault`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that ultimately worked for me.  I asked an actual developer this question instead of trying to figure it out myself (I'm QA) :)  I had to add some special logic to format the string properly because the attr.TestCategories object is a List.

```
//find method with testcategory attribute
if (attrs.Any(x => x is TestCategoryAttribute))
{
    var testCategoryAttrs = attrs.Where(x => x is TestCategoryAttribute);
    if (testCategoryAttrs.Any())
    {
        foreach (var testCategoryAttr in testCategoryAttrs)
        {
            TestCategoryAttribute attr = (TestCategoryAttribute)testCategoryAttr;
            testCategories += string.IsNullOrEmpty(testCategories)
                ? string.Join(", ", attr.TestCategories)
                : string.Format(", {0}", string.Join(", ", attr.TestCategories));
        }
    }                               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `SingleOrDefault` with the `Where`:

```
var testcategoryAttrs = attrs.Where(x => x is TestCategoryAttribute)
                             .Select(x => ((TestCategoryAttribute)x).TestCategory);
string testCategories = string.Join(", ", testcategoryAttrs.ToArray());
```

*I don't know the property name in the `TestCategoryAttribute`, so I used the `TestCategory` in this sample.*

Comment: you solution didn't quite work because the ToArray() produced a list of object types and not the actual values.

Comment: It is very odd. Try to redeclare the `testcategoryAttrs` as `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `var`. And please make sure that you replaced the `TestCategory` property in my sample with a real property name, that returns attribute's data string.

Answer (score 0):

`SingleOrDefault` throws an exception if there is more than one item that mathes with your condition.In this case you have two attributes and that's why you are getting the exception.

If you want to get only one item, then use `FirstOrDefault`. It returns the first item that mathces with the condition otherwise it returns *null* so you should be careful when casting returning result of `FirstOrDefault`, you may want to add a null-check before the cast,since you are using `Any` method and make sure there is at least one `TestCategoryAttribute` exists, null-check is not necessary in this case.

```
var testcategoryAttr = (TestCategoryAttribute)attrs
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x is TestCategoryAttribute);
```